# ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio in python 3.8 and when i execute

```
pip3 install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

it shows an error that

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Did you try  pip install PyAudio ?

Comment: That wheel is specifically for python 3.8 on 64bit Windows. what are you running?

Comment: I mentioned above Python 3.8 and 64bit yes.

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

If this doesn't work, you can manually add and install pyaudio.

First, go to: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
and check the pyaudio supporting to your Python version.

For example: if you have Python 3.8.2, then `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

After downloading, copy that file and paste it in `C://Users/[user]/`

Then open cmd and write:

```
pip install [full filename]
```

If this doesn't work, change the file directory to
`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`
Then restart cmd and run again `pip install [full filename]`.

Comment: As you said put it in user then install but its not working.and even in scripts its not working.

Comment: Same issue here, but installing it outside the virtual environment seems to have no errors. But still i want it inside venv. i think it is some kind of a bug in python3.8 since it is still newly released

Comment: Even after deactivating venv same error happens in python3.8.5. Seems no solution working for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Mac OSX do:

```
brew install portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 1):

Check version:

```
python --version
```

You need:

```
py -3.9 -m pip install [name packege]
```

"-3.9" - own Python version

Example:

```
py -3.9 -m pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Throw the error:

`py: error: unrecognized arguments: -m pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

download pyaudio from:

```
lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio
```

installing PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
I have error:

```
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

But `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`
install successful:

```
pip install .\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\sje\downloads\pyaudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
Successfully installed PyAudio-0.2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

open run and type appdata and go to programs python38 and open file name script in that file past that download 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64' and in that path address click and type cmd and enter open cmd than type pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64 and enter.
Done

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was upgrading to the latest pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

After that the install succeeded.

Answer (score -2):

Bro, this is a very easy fix. I was playing around with the wheel file directory and I wondered if it would work in the projects venv/scripts directory, and IT WORKS :)
Don't forget to use cmd and use:
pip install (full filename)