# Unable to install pyaudio in VScode 3.8.5 on windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pyaudio

> 

I try to install pyaudio on windows using pip from a wheel package as follow:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl
```

unfortunately it raise an error as presented below. The error message tells that my pyaudio wheel unable to be founded.

```
WARNING: Requirement 'PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file 
does not exist
ERROR: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

What should I do to solve this issue and install pyaudio correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [StackOverflow - How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about the formatting of your questions. Questions which are formatted inline with the rules will receive better responses from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was raised due to pip unable to locate the wheel file. Try to specify a full path such as:

```
pip install D:/../<file_name>.whl
```

or move your wheel file to the same directory as your pip.

Comment: Even though I'm not getting it

Comment: C:\Users\user>C:/Users/user/JARVIS_Virtual_Assistant(Python)/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
'C:/Users/user/JARVIS_Virtual_Assistant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It means: pip install C:/Users/user/JARVIS_Virtual_Assistant(Python)/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl, if it not work, you could move the file to D drive and change the command to: pip install D:/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl.

Comment: @Vishwa if you have more than one python version installed you may need to specify for which python the package should installed. For example, you have python 3.9 & 3.7 installed and you want to install the package for python 3.7. then you must call the pip of your python 3.7 i.e. <python37_pathname> -m pip install wheel.whl.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho Even though I'm not getting.

Comment: @Vishwa I'm trying to find another solution for you. I find an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348555/error-pyaudio-0-2-11-cp38-cp38-win-amd64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-p) on issue installing pyaudio in virtual environment. You can check answer by Deepak Singh Rajput on that post.