# Unable to install PyAudio on Python 3.9

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm trying to install PyAudio on Python 3.9 and it is not working. I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\koffie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8fxj755j\\pyaudio_3c7b865f50cd493eaf257dea132d1fe1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\koffie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8fxj755j\\pyaudio_3c7b865f50cd493eaf257dea132d1fe1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\koffie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9go3oms0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio'   
         cwd: C:\Users\koffie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8fxj755j\pyaudio_3c7b865f50cd493eaf257dea132d1fe1\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\koffie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8fxj755j\\pyaudio_3c7b865f50cd493eaf257dea132d1fe1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\koffie\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8fxj755j\\pyaudio_3c7b865f50cd493eaf257dea132d1fe1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\koffie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9go3oms0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\koffie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried downloading Visual Basic Tools, as well as, I have tried doing the pip install pipwin and then PyAudio function. But unfortunately the same error occurred. I also tried downloading the following and installing it: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl

I am trying to build an Alexa-like AI, and need this PyAudio package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win\_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348555/error-pyaudio-0-2-11-cp38-cp38-win-amd64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-p)

Comment: *I also tried downloading the following and installing it: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl* That should have worked. If it did not, it certainly gave you a different error message. What was it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `pip install pipwin` and then `pipwin install pyaudio`? pipwin is designed to work on Windows, so you may have better luck with it.

Comment: Hi, i have tried doin the pipwin and the pyaudio, unfortunately i get the same error still as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As of today 10-03-2022 , you have following options:

- use python 3.6 (wheels available), probably you don't want to give up on the latest python version because of this dependency, but this is an easy option.
- you [build it](https://smaudet.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/building-pyaudio-on-windows-7-x64-using-the-free-msvc-toolchains/) from source, probably will take you some effort.
- you download the wheel package from [gohlke's page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) and tell pip to use that wheel instead of downloading it from pypi.