# ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. on heroku

Tags: django, github, heroku, deployment

ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. while deploying to heroku.I also install this error file in my system.

Comment: Is that answer solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61348555/error-pyaudio-0-2-11-cp38-cp38-win-amd64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-p